# Inserting a component between 2 AddRegistry.registerComponent throws error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My React Native 0.70 app requires an addition of a privacy page presented to users before AddRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js. Here is index.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App0 from './App0';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App0);
```

The component App0 is added as below to present user the privacy policy and register the root component AGAIN of the app which is App:

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import Bye from "./src/components/app/Bye";
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
import helper from "./src/lib/helper";
import {
    heightPercentageToDP as hp,
    widthPercentageToDP as wp,
   } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

export default function App0() {
    const [hasToken, setHasToken] = useState(false);
    const [hasYes, setHasYes] = useState(false);
    const [hasBye, setHasBye] = useState(false)

    const userYes = () => {
        setHasYes(true);
        //AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
    };

    const PrivacyPolicy = () => {
        console.log("In PrivacyPolicy");
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:60}}>
                <WebView
                style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20, width:wp("80%"), height:hp("75%"), fontSize:wp("2.5%")}}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{ uri: `https://emclab.github.io` }} 
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                />
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{userYes()}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:wp("3.5%"), color:"blue"}}>ACCEPT POLICY</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>      </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setHasBye(true)}} >
                        <Text style={{fontSize:wp("3.5%"), color:"blue"}}>REJECT POLICY</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const asynctask = async () => {
            console.log("in asynctask");
            try {
                //let my_id = await helper.secureGet("myID"); //viewer_id      
                let _result = await helper.getJwtToken(); //JWT token and secret
                if (!_result) {
                    setHasToken(false);
                } else {
                    setHasToken(true);
                };
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error in App0.js : ", err);
                setHasToken(false);
            };
            
        };
    
        asynctask();

    }, []);
    
    const AppTran = () => {
        
        AppRegistry.registerRunnable(appName, () => { 
            AppRegistry.unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag(AppRegistry.getAppKeys()?.indexOf(appName));
            const App = require('./App').default;
            const codePush = require('react-native-code-push').default;
            AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => codePush(App));;
        });    
    };

    return (<>
            {(hasYes || hasToken) && <AppTran />}
            {!hasToken && !hasYes && !hasBye && <PrivacyPolicy />}
            {hasBye && <Bye />}
            </>); 
};
```

The code does present the privacy page and works fine when user rejects the policy. However when user accepts the policy, it renders a blank screen without error. Just nothing on the screen.

Here is root keys `AppRegistry.getAppKeys())` console output.

```
LOG  AppRegistry keys :  ["LogBox", "xyz_app6"]. //<<==xyz_app6 is appName
```